# Computing $\langle p|e^{iH\Delta t/\hbar}|x_0\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, path-integral

I'm new on path integral methods and bra ket notation and, while as was reading [these Berkeley 221A Lecture Notes on the
Path Integral](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/pathintegral.pdf) by  Hitoshi Murayama (2006), I found

> The propagator for a short interval of time is given by the Lagrangian $$
> \langle x_1,t+\Delta t|x_0,t\rangle 
> =K_1e^{i(L(t)\Delta t+O(\Delta t)^2)/\hbar}, \tag{5}
> $$ 
>   where $K_1$ is a normalitzation constant.
>
> Considering an easy Hamiltonian such as $$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+V,\tag{6}$$ 
>   $$
> \langle x_1,t+\Delta t|x_0,t\rangle 
> =\langle x_1|e^{iH\Delta t/\hbar}|x_0\rangle 
> =\int dp \langle x_1|p\rangle \langle p|e^{iH\Delta t/\hbar}|x_0\rangle .\tag{7}
> $$

And, focusing on the second term (I know that $\langle x_1|p\rangle = \frac{ e^{-ipx_1/\hbar} }{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}$) one can obtain

> \begin{align}
> \langle p|e^{iH\Delta t/\hbar}|x_0\rangle 
> & =\langle p|1-iH\Delta t/\hbar+O(\Delta t)^2|x_0\rangle 
> \\ & =\left[1-{\frac{p^2}{2m}\frac{i}{\hbar}\Delta t-\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x_0)\Delta t+O(\Delta t)^2}\right] \frac{e^{-ipx_0/\hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}
> \\ & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\exp\frac{-i}{\hbar}\left(px_0+\frac{p^2}{2m}\Delta t+V(x_0)\Delta t+O(\Delta t)^2\right). \tag{8}
> \end{align}

I can follow evertything except the last step, can someone explain it with more detail? (or only what's the key idea to understand)

Comment: The lecture notes are just Taylor expanding the exponential function in the very last step.

Comment: But why tehre's still and exponential function if you expand it with Taylor (I'm really confused why is all inside an exponential)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that he has done is rewrite,
$$(1-\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{p^2\Delta t}{2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x_0)\Delta t + O(\Delta t^2))=exp(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{p^2\Delta t}{2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x_0)\Delta t + O(\Delta t^2)).$$
Then simply moved out the $-i\hbar$,
$$exp(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\frac{p^2\Delta t}{2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V(x_0)\Delta t + O(\Delta t^2))=exp\bigg[\frac{-i}{\hbar}\bigg(+\frac{p^2\Delta t}{2}+V(x_0)\Delta t + O(\Delta t^2)\bigg)\bigg]$$
If you multiply this with, $$\frac{e^{-ipx_0/\hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}},$$
then you get the expression you are looking for.

Comment: I feel stupid right now, it's all about $e^x\cdot e^y=e^{x+y}$, I wasn't able to see, I was looknig for something more  complicated